# cmd /C set variable

Tags: variables, cmd, keepass

The short:
I am trying to make a 1 line command script that sets and uses a variable. Right now I came up with:

```
cmd /C "set var=127.0.0.1 & echo %var%"
```

I would expect it to output 127.0.0.1, but instead it prints %var%.

The long:
I am using keepass as a password manager and trying to make it automatically launch a RDP session for me. I put the following in the URL:

```
cmd://cmd /C "cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/127.0.0.1 /user:{USERNAME} /pass:{PASSWORD} & mstsc.exe /v:127.0.0.1 & cmdkey /delete:TERMSRV/127.0.0.1"
```

This works, but if I need to update the ipaddress, I have to touch 3 places instead of just 1. I tried changing it to the following, but it didn't work:

```
cmd://cmd /C "set sServer=127.0.0.1 & cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/%sServer% /user:{USERNAME} /pass:{PASSWORD} & mstsc.exe /v:%sServer% & cmdkey /delete:TERMSRV/%sServer%"
```

Comment: Can't understand why the _1 line command script_ condition, but `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` and `echo !var!` should help. Learn more on [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: The one line requirements comes from keepass. Its cmd:// ability only allows you to run 1 command. I've tried a couple of variants with DelayedExpansion, but haven't found the correct combo yet.

Somebody had an answer posted a day ago, but now its gone...

Comment: Another approach: `cmd://cmd /C "for /F "tokens=*" %G in ("127.0.0.1") do cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/%G /user:{USERNAME} /pass:{PASSWORD} & mstsc.exe /v:%G & cmdkey /delete:TERMSRV/%G"`. As I know nothing about `keepass` instead `%G` might be `%%G` [as in a batch script](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) shoud be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

josefZ comment worked perfectly. The following command can be placed in the "URL:" field in keepass. When you double click the url or do anything else that launches the url it will automatically launch RPD and log you in.

```
cmd://cmd /C "for /F "tokens=*" %G in ("127.0.0.1") do cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/%G /user:{USERNAME} /pass:{PASSWORD} & mstsc.exe /v:%G & cmdkey /delete:TERMSRV/%G"
```

I have tested this by RDPing into both a Windows box and a Linux box.